# Legs from 3/4 plywood.. load capacity

Tags: plywood

I am designing a 5'x6.5' loft bed. 4-5 years down the line, I'd like to be able to remove (or trim) and throw away legs ( and any under-bed furniture) and be able to use it as a regular bed afterwards. This is a DIY project.

This will primarily be used by my 5 year old, but should be capable of handling at least 1 adult's weight also.

I am looking for help to determine if the legs, as designed, would hold up for the purpose.
If not, what would be possible leg design I could make up with 3/4 inch plywood that can do the job. I prefer to use only one kind of raw-material, because of limited tools I have available.

Design details:

Overall assembly is shown in following images:

[image: full assembly-angle-1]

[image: full-assembly-angle-2]

The legs are also supported at bottom as shown in first image.
There will be one desk, one two-seat-bench and one long shelf above these supports. Behind all those furniture, I'll add additional vertical supports (at least 12 high") to legs, hopefully arresting any racking. Legs will not be bearing weight of any furniture other than bed frame.

Legs assembly and attachment are as shown in following image:

[image: leg assembly]

Each leg is L-shaped corner assembly of two pieces 64"x5.5" plywood sheets.

I have sketched up two possible corner joints as shown in second image:
(left) with 6 inch thick laps/fingers joint with a 8mm dowel every 6 inches and
(right) finger joint with 1 inch fingers.

Cleats are glued and screwed to bed-frame. Legs will insert into cleat+frame corners as shown. Legs will be bolted to frame with 8pcs M6 bolts in each corner. Frame will have a D-nut insert for each bolt.

I feel that rest of design would be OK, but I am not able to find any resources on strength of plywood in the configuration as being used in legs. So, not sure if legs would hold up.

[Update-1]

1. Updated full assembly diagrams to show positioning of stairs, and internal structure panels added for arresting racking.

[Update-2]

2. New leg design, made from 4pcs of 3" wide plywood arranged as a hollow square. How would this compare to a solid leg made of 4 pcs of 3" plywood pieces laminated together? I believe hollow tube would be stronger than solid core, if cross-section area is same (can't recall where I heard that)

[image: hollow-square-leg]

Comment: If the assembly is not secured to the walls (say in a corner), you may need some lateral/diagonal bracing to keep the assembly for racking in one or both directions.

Comment: Thanks Ashlar. I am not much worried about racking. I am actually concerned whether the let's will hold up the required weight, or if not, what is the best way to beef them up

Comment: You won't easily be cutting box joints over this length! In fact it may be so difficult as to be impossible on a practical level. So yeah, definitely look at another option for the L-shaped leg assemblies.

Comment: Are you set on the idea of formal legs? Since you're using plywood you're missing out on one of its fundamental properties if you don't use it, at least in part, as a sheet material. If the back and rear use full pieces of ply (with cutouts for lightness and/or aesthetics) then there's almost no limit to the weight that rear corner can support, and racking becomes an impossibility for all intents and purposes. If you insist on using ply for the front leg then I would laminate up a sandwich of 3 pieces, that will make it nearly as strong as solid wood.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks. I have avoided using fully covered sides because that require me to join two panels into 60"x64" total and I am not entirely sure how to achieve that in a way that retains strength.

Comment: @Graphus If I make three layer sandwich of 5" wide and 64" long, so each leg is 5"x2.25"x64", do you think it can support the weight easily? Would it be better to sandwich 4 layers and make up a 3"x3"x64" legs instead?

Comment: I believe even 2 panels are strong enough to support the weight.  The problem is that the legs could bow in the middle so the width must be great enough to resist this tendency.  3 " should be adequate if the layers are fully glued up so that the piece acts as a unit.

Comment: Just a detail I noticed that probably doesn't matter now since you seem to have abandoned the finger joints. Your dowels in the left leg image seem to go the wrong direction. They appear to go through the plys of one single piece of wood, instead of pinning one piece of ply to the other, which was, I believe your intention. I don't think it would matter, because I don't think pinning into the thickness of plywood is a good idea anyway.

Comment: As a thought, use a sheet(s) of plywood on the short ends and carve the ladder directly out of the ply. That would give you the strength of the sheet and a built in ladder without any additional construction. Then use a single leg in each corner on the long direction made out of some sort of solid wood. The only cut on this one would be to length, so there would be no need for additional tooling. Screw/dowel the plywood ends to the vertical legs and add a decorative ply fillet in the corner to resist racking in the long direction.

Comment: Agree that L-shaped plywood legs don't seem like a good idea. However, you could build them, see what you think, and add a stick of lumber (2x4 or thereabouts) on the inside corner to stiffen up the assembly. (Glue and screw the lumber.) 3x3 plywood laminate might work, though I'd consider assembling them in a way that has one of the ply segments perpendicular to the rest. (Ping back if you want a sketch of that.) All that said, you'd spend a lot less time (and only a bit more money) just using a 4x4 wood post.

Comment: *"...require me to join two panels into 60"x64" total and I am not entirely sure how to achieve that in a way that retains strength"* Easy, just glue them together as a long butt joint and add dowels or screws (longish ones) through the flat of one sheet into the end of the second. To strengthen further (largely for peace of mind I feel, rather than being absolutely necessary) you can reinforce, e.g. with a full-height internal glue block, spaced individual glue blocks, plywood gussets, all of which should be glued and nailed in place or glued and screwed.

Comment: *"Would it be better to sandwich 4 layers and make up a 3"x3"x64" legs instead?"* It  would certainly be stronger, quite a bit stronger. Not sure if it's necessary to be honest, but erring on the side of too strong rather than too weak is never a bad idea when constructing something like this. Without a gut feeling about a material, from long experience using it, trying various things, having some failures (or I suppose never having one, because you always err on the side of caution and nothing fails) it's always best to go for an option you suspect is overkill, just to be on the safe side :-)

Comment: @Freeman: Yes, dowels were drawn on wrong fingers, they were meant to go from one piece's face to other's edge. Also, I am making a staircase, because I don't want vertical ladder for climbing up.

Comment: @Freeman, Graphus, the overall structure has bounding box dimensions of: 61.5" depth, 79.5" length and 80" height. This means that none of the side faces can be made in single sheet of plywood. And I don't know how to join two sheets on edge to create a wider sheet.

Comment: @Ashlar: Thanks. You're probably right; if the legs fail, the'd do so by bowing.

Comment: I originally designed in L- shaped legs, they have a single (long) joint and leave a lot of surface are to work with where I join them with bed-frame. based on multiple suggerstions here, I think it's better to double up the thickness of plywood available for length, which means my legs would be made of four panels instead of 2. So, is it better to mke them into a square, instead of a solid? Perhaps I'll update question with a diagram

Comment: Thanks for the update and the new images, they make a big difference to understanding the thing as currently envisaged. Just to reiterate, ditch the idea of the finger-jointed long edges, you'll likely never accomplish those and they're not needed for strength. The new addition, the central — and wide — stretcher pieces change things considerably here, for the better and I feel all stability *and* strength concerns go away, because they will effectively remove any chance of the legs bowing outward, as well as probably eliminating racking.

Comment: *"the overall structure has bounding box dimensions of: 61.5" depth, 79.5" length and 80" height. This means that none of the side faces can be made in single sheet of plywood."* Yes sorry, I wasn't thinking it through fully darn it.

Comment: I just noticed that the tops of the legs appear to be half-lapped into the bed frame. I'm not so sure that a half-lap joint in plywood is a great idea.

Comment: @FreeMan, yes, one other aspect of the proposed design that needs input, but one problem at a time.

Comment: @FreeMan The legs were designed half lapped only partially, and that was not done for strength. Idea was that, once legs have bottom and mid horizontal panels  bolted, and legs are standing, they should slot into top frame corners, without needing four people to hold up the structure while it is being bolted during assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The square legs would be considerably stronger than just the 2-sided legs, but honestly what is wrong with using 2x4's for the legs? You only have to cut them to length and you can nail 2 together for added strength if you want.  On top of that you can cover them up with the plywood if you want to have that look, without all the trouble of putting finger joints in plywood.  Now if you're using 1" plywood, maybe, but then the cost would be cheaper at that point to go with 2x4's and cover them with cheaper 1/4" plywood.

unfortunately I don't have numbers to back it up, but plywood legs makes me itch with 'not safe'.

the other issue I see, are not enough triangles to keep things from 'racking', unless you plan to run some lag bolts into the wall on 2 sides.

Comment: Honestly I agree that just using solid wood for the legs would just be so much easier, and if painting the mix of materials doesn't even matter than much (although as you say you could skin with plywood for the look). But re. triangles and racking, if overall construction is strong and stiff enough there's no need for triangles, q. v. most hand-tool workbenches. I believe the wide central rails in the updated sketches have that well covered now, if fastened securely.

Comment: I guess the only place I'd have some concern about the triangles are on the 'front', Not a lot of concern, but some.